# My mother was a refused a UK visa due to her previous visa application containing an erroneous statement. What are my options?

Tags: visa-refusals, uk-residents, nigeria

[image: Reason for visa denial]

My mother was denied a visa to attend my graduation and she has been crying since she received this heartbreaking news. I really want her to attend my graduation. How do I remedy this problem?

After working for an organisation, she started her own business and she attached a document showing her business registration and business account details.

The last application she did was done by an agent as she was feeling poorly during that period. So the agent mentioned that she has no relative or dependent.

Comment: @MadHatter Not a complete dup because here they have also got OP's mother on 4.3(a) which means they doubt the relationship between OP and her mother.

Comment: This really isn't a duplicate of the canonical question. The visa has been refused under those rules, but the real problem is a previous application, about which we know little, which is at odds with the current one. The OPs mother is lucky not to have been refused under Section V 3.6.

Comment: @CannonFodder What is V 3.6?

Comment: @Benubird submitting false documents

Comment: When is your graduation? If it's this year this may be a lost cause. If you're desperate for them to attend consider asking if the University can delay your ceremony until next year.

Comment: Sorry I feel bad for your mother but this will not fly under any circumstances especially in the UK or the United States.  If you claim something and then you suddenly change it they keep track of all of this stuff.  Unfortunately you will not be able to see your mother during your graduation - as harsh as it sounds it is just impossible now.

Comment: @benubird As Thomas Yates says, section V 3.6 covers submission of false documents and deception. A refusal under  V 3.6 would almost certainly lead to a ten year ban under V 3.7 should the OP's mother apply again.

Comment: @Crazymoomin My impression is that UK universities generally have more than one graduation ceremony each year and that people can generally graduate whenever they want. But will delaying make any difference? I doubt the asker's mother will be able to get a visa next year, either.

Comment: @DavidRicherby the ceremony itself is really just a formality, you don't actually need to attend at all to graduate (they don't even give you your certificate there nowadays, that comes in the post). So OP could in theory still graduate this year and attend a ceremony next year. As for getting a visa, well you may be right, but an extra year may just be enough time to get this mess sorted out, if it can be sorted.

Comment: You edited your question to remove all the content; please don't do that.  We want to save your question so that it can be useful to other people in the future.

Answer (score 102):

Your mother has got herself into something of a pickle. UK immigration appear to have declarations from her saying she is retired, and that she has no offspring. Now, she's applying for a visa with both those declarations apparently in error.

This casts serious doubt on her credibility, and overcoming that doubt will be an uphill struggle. Not only does she now have to document exactly her current situation, but she must also explain how those errors came about.

This will not be easily fixed, if it can be fixed at all. She needs the advice of a lawyer with expertise in UK immigration - strangers on the internet will not be enough.

You might start with a call to the [UK Law Society](http://www.lawsociety.org.uk/for-the-public/using-a-solicitor/find-a-solicitor/)

Expect this to be expensive.

Comment: +1 No easy fix to having given contradicting info on two applications. OP is lucky they did not get her mother for deception. (Or maybe they did and it is mentioned in second part of refusal notice)

Comment: More likely whoever you speak to will advise you that pushing this issue will end up with your mother being charged for fraud if she can't prove exactly why her two forms were so different.

Comment: getting this mess sorted out's not going to be easy, if doable at all.  People can decide to re-enter the workforce after retiring - either because they found their savings inadequate, or just because they got bored - but unless the prior application is at least ~20 years old the "no kids" issue is damning.

Comment: I guess this could serve as a warning not to use agents under any circumstances, even if unwell (either tough it out or get a close relative to help). Though I'm pretty unfamiliar with the profession as I've never seen such services advertised in my country.

Comment: Without question, the immigration officer will say "I don't care who prepared it, you bloody signed it!"

Comment: Is there any remedy at all.. As I am looking for solutions now

Comment: Yes. Talk to a lawyer yesterday.

Comment: @DanNeely I could excuse that as misunderstanding the question. One's son or daughter who is over 18 and studying at university is not a child.

Comment: @TomW This is immigration we're talking about - they're not going to buy that at all.  Given that the issue is that her credibility is shot, trying to worm out of it by telling more lies isn't going to help any.   When in a hole - stop digging.

Comment: By that I meant "that could reasonably be the truth". Both of the stated contradictions have reasonable explanations; the applicant was retired at the last application but now they are working again, and they have offspring who are no longer children

Comment: @tomw We're into speculation here. We do know that the issues of retirement and children have been cited in a refusal notice, so they have to be dealt with in any new application. Speculating further, I'd guess that the previous application was also refused (a retiree with no dependents may be considered unlikely to want to return home), so this is a second rejection, and expert advice is now called for.